# Is it possible to block the Borderlands 2 executables with firewall and play it coop with a friend on Evolve at the same time?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to block the BL2 executables with firewall and play it coop with a friend on Evolve at the same time?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: What firewall are you using? What operative system?

Comment: Chances are extremely good that blocking it at the firewall level will prevent Evolve from doing it's job.

Comment: windows 7 built in firewall; windows 7 x64

Comment: What features of Evolve are you looking to retain after the BL2 exe has been blocked?

Comment: im looking for a possibility to block it from connecting to the internet but allowing connections via vpn tunnel

Comment: @nicetry - Why don't you just play it on Evolve without blocking it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you block it. If you add a rule that blocks all incoming connections, you might have an issue if you try to host a LAN game over the Evolve VPN, but it should otherwise be able to connect to a LAN game. If you block all outbound connections, it won't work at all, as it will block even attempts to view other local games.